# is there a word or expression which describes a mapping between the same thing?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

For example, if I map 4 to 4, 4000 to 4000,
is there a good word or expression which describes this kind of mapping?

Perhaps *identity mapping* or something else?

Comment: _Identity mapping_ is one; _symbolism_ is another; _exact 1-1 map_ another, etc. Depends on what you're really mapping, and what kind of map - onto, into, open, closed, etc. And what "the same thing" means: for instance, what kind of map is [1, 2, 3, ...] -> ["one", "two", "three", ...]?

Comment: just map from [1, 2, 3, ...] -> [1, 2, 3, ...]

Comment: Strings are different from integers. Or are we talking math? Any identity transformation will work; the [cyclic group of 4](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Groupof4.pdf) can be mapped onto [1, i, -1, -i] to produce a group that's homeomorphic to the rotational symmetry group of a square. So which "same thing" are we talking about here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a mathematician, I would call that an identity map; that is, a function that does not change the domain (start) when mapped to the range (finish). You could also call it an identity transformation, identity relation, or identity function.

If the domain changes form but the underlying structure is not affected, you can call it an isomorphic map (the map must be reversible as well, or else it would be a called homomorphic map). For example, (1,2,3,...) mapped to (one, two, three,...) is an isomorphic map, not an identity map. By its nature, the identity map is also an isomorphic map.